# Using align inside cases

Tags: align, cases, mathjax

I was trying to achieve an alignment inside a cases environment. Here is what I was trying to achieve:

[image]

I actually was able to achieve the above using the following MathJax code:

```
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
\begin{align*}
x&=1, & y&=1 \\
x&=10, & y&=20
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$
```

I realize that `$$` is not proper LaTeX syntax, but I'm not sure what to substitute it with.

Now, when I try to put this inside a LaTeX document, it gives me a few errors and doesn't line everything up properly into two columns (there is only one column).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
\begin{align*}
x&=1, & y&=1 \\
x&=10, & y&=20
\end{align*}
\end{cases}
$$

\end{document}
```

Here is something else I tried, which reduced the graphical errors, but still puts it inside only one column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
u &= \ln x & v' &= 1 \\
u' &= \frac{1}{x} & v &= x \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I would also like to control the spacing with the `alignat` environment, but I need to find out how to do this first before I can start thinking about that :)

Comment: `texdoc amsmath` ? `align` is a display environment (you can use `aligned` for subterms.

Comment: the latex equivalent to `$$..$$` (which is also the mathjax default) is `\[..\]`

Comment: Don't use`$$ ... $$`. See the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: MathJax is not LaTeX; it (wrongly) allows constructions that are illegal as LaTeX code and this is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to use  `empheq + alignat*`. Needless to load `amsmath`, since `empheq` loads `mathtools`, which does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={f(x, y)=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat*=2}
    x &=1, &\quad y &=1 \\
    x &=10, & y &=20
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

`align` is for complete display math, `aligned` is the version for subterms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
f(x,y) = 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x&=1, & y&=1 \\
x&=10, & y&=20
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```